# Set maxlength in html input without changing form width?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a sign up form and want to limit the length of the First Name and Last Name fields to 50 characters.

The problem is, when I do, the form displays much wider.

How can I make sure the user cannot enter more than 50 characters into those form fields ***without*** it affecting the width of the form?

#### Reference

Here is the code/result before and after (the only change is the addition of the `maxlength: 50` to the form helper.

**Before**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "First Name", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, autocomplete: "Last Name", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

[image]

**After** (too wide):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, maxlength: 50, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "First Name", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, maxlength: 50, autocomplete: "Last Name", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't realised, but when rails sees `maxwidth: 50`, it automatically adds: `size: 50`.

I simply add a `size: 25` to the form field helper and the width of those fields becomes 25 rather than 50

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, maxlength: 50, size: 25, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "First Name", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, maxlength: 50, size: 25, autocomplete: "Last Name", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```